# "dd/MM/yyyy" matches invalid date "05/20/2019"

Tags: java, date

I'm using [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse dates in my application and for some reason I get completely unexpected results for some formats.

I have the following test, but it fails because no exception is thrown:

```
Assert.assertThrows(ParseException.class, () -> {
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("05/20/2019");
});
```

Even more surprising, if I print the result of the parse, it returns the following value: `Wed Aug 05 00:00:00 CEST 2020`.

I have no idea where "August" could even come from.

Is there any explanation to the behavior, and a way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: use `LocalDate`

Comment: The simple answer: your month 20 is 12+8, which makes an overflow in the year (+12 months = + 1 year), and the rest is month number 8 which is August. But also not happy that such a value is accepted by a class which normally processes(and validates!) end-user input

Comment: It's basically adding 12 months to the date, so 05/08/2019 + 12 months -> 05/08/2020

Comment: I would double check the format you have provided to SimpleDateFormat and the argument you have given to parse and determine if that matches what you want

Comment: You can use JUnit 5, and you're still using `SimpleDateFormat` from Java 1.1? Excuse me, there's an upgrade you need a lot more urgently than that to the latest JUnit version. `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome and was replaced with the release of Java 8 more than 5 years ago. You have seen only one of its very many bad habits. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` and trivially obtain the behaviour you had expected (you will get a `DateTimeParseException`).